# I want to return the contents of file using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have written the following code in protractor.

### helper.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
helper = function(){
    this.blnReturn = function(){
        var filePath = '../Protractor_PgObjModel/Results/DontDelete.txt';
        fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, data){
            if (!err) {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            } else {
               return "False";
            }
        });
    };
};
module.exports = new helper();
```

------------actual file where the above js is being called-------------------

```
describe("read contents of file",function(){
  var helper = require("../GenericUtilities/helper.js");
  it('To Test read data',function(){
    console.log("helper test - " + helper.blnReturn());   
  });
});
```

-------Output-------------

```
helper test - undefined
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated as it is blocking my work.

Comment: replace `fs.readFileSync` with `return fs.readFileSync`

Answer (score 2):

you are confusing between reading file synchronously(`readFileSync`) and async(`readFile`).

you are trying to read the file synchronously, but also using a callback parameter, the right way would be either

```
return fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
```

or

```
this.blnReturn = function(cb){
    ...
    fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, data){
        if (!err) {
            console.log(data);
            cb(data);
        } else {
           cb("False");
        }
    });
```

also, on an unrelated note, `var` keyword is missing in `helper` definition,  the helper.js can be reduced to:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function helper(){}

helper.prototype.blnReturn = function(){
    var filePath = '../request.js';
    return fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
};

module.exports = new helper();
```

Comment: I tried all your logic but still returns Null values and data is present in the referring file.Is there any other approach which can help me out.

Comment: can you tell me what this gives you `console.log('data: , 'fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));`

Comment: It is returning an empty value and the text file contains a string "True"

Comment: can you just show your project structure, try giving an absolute location of file and check if it works...